# Cannot figure out how to use the OfficeExtension.Promise

Tags: es6-promise, office-js, office-js-helpers

Currently I am trying to use the OfficeExtension.Promise polyfill offered by Microsoft for developing Office Add-Ins. Unfortunately I am not able to get it to work thus far. From what I can tell these are only offered in the WordApi 1.2 and ExcelApi 1.2. Since I could not find separate node modules offering these api's I presume that these are included in the normal '@microsoft/office-js' node module. Additionally I have installed the office-js types as well.

**Node modules**

[image: Node modules]

**Import statements**

So far I have tried importing the 'OfficeExtension' class/namespace in the following ways.

```
import {OfficeExtension} from '@microsoft/office-js'
import {OfficeExtension} from 'office-js'
import {OfficeExtension} from '@types/office-js'
```

**Error**

All of these result in an intellisense error stating that the module cannot be found.

[image: Error]

**Question**

The concrete problem is that I do not know how to import the functionality in order to use the OfficeExtension.Promise polyfill. I could find no documentation that offers any help on this topic, so any advice or information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the error that is shown, actually states what is happening. 'office-js' does not export a module that can be used in a Typescript/React project. Office or OfficeExtension are global variables on the 'Window'. Therefore a ///  tag or another script reference is needed, in order to import these variables.

[Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11420)